# How to align text both sides(justify)

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

Is there any way to align the text to the both right and left sides of the including rectangel using c++?

Like this;

[image]

Comment: Which environment? A mono-space console? A remotely controlled web browser? Anything inbetween?

Comment: In any case, most likely there is a way to justify the text.

Comment: Except in the case you don't know the character width of the console - then you are stuck to left alignment.

Comment: not console application. windows form application

Comment: That should be specified in the question itself

Comment: @MOD You mean windows forms?  .Net GUI framework?

Comment: i added to the question

Comment: It's not clear yet from the question.

Comment: i mean using handle windows in c++. I am new at c++ thats why i cant understand what you mean exactly

Comment: I was getting ready to type about string handling, identifying the spaces in the text and distributing more spaces to accomplish text justification.

Comment: that would also be fine

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Rich Edit control can do this starting from Version 3.0.  Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.  Search for `PFA_JUSTIFY` in that page.

Comment: You need to tell us more about your system, you know far more than we do. You should have `richedit.h`; if you don't then you need to work out why.

Comment: ok i can use richedit now. but i need something like

justfiy(text);

Is it possible to do it via Richedit?